# Unable to select text inside div in Three.js

Tags: javascript, css, dom, three.js, css-selectors

I have created a 3d interactive animation using Three.js. I have created a Div that sits on top of the rendered objects in space. I have set the z-index property to be higher for the div so that I can select text inside. However I am having when I try to select the text the objects underneath the div are selected. I would like to achieve the same effect here: http://wiki.polyfra.me/# he has div elements overlaid on the 3d objects and you can select text.

Comment: you don't have any of these div's as static right?  it's impossible to help further since you don't post any code.  I can say z-index does not respond to static elements, other than that, there is not much to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's interactive I'm assuming your using OrbitControls.

If so, do this:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

This way, the OrbitControl will only work when nothing is on top of the scene.